# LOCK IN SHARE MODE and FOR UPDATE vs nothing in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, select, transactions, mariadb

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32827650/mysql-innodb-difference-between-for-update-and-lock-in-share-mode) compares `SELECT...LOCK IN SHARE MODE` and `SELECT...FOR UPDATE`. However, how are these 2 different from the bare `SELECT` inside a transaction? The database is MariaDB, but MySQL answer should be fine too if there are no differences. Most importantly, I need the info in the context of avoiding DB deadlocks.

Answer (score 2):

Many deadlocks can be avoided; some cannot.  There is no single technique to prevent all deadlocks.

`FOR UPDATE` seems to be more useful than `LOCK IN SHARE MODE`.  (I would be interested to hear someone argue the contrary.)

The usual pattern seems to be:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;  -- use the columns fetched; lock the row(s)
-- Note:  the locked rows may or may not actually be UPDATEd later
-- Note:  FOR UDPATE prevents other connections from grabbing the same row(s)
UPDATE/DELETE/... -- those rows.
COMMIT;
```

But... Nothing above prevents the classic deadlock scenario:

```
BEGIN;   -- connection 1
SELECT row 123 FOR UPDATE;
SELECT row 234 FOR UPDATE;
...
```

Versus

```
BEGIN;   -- connection 1
SELECT row 234 FOR UPDATE;
SELECT row 123 FOR UPDATE;  -- Note: locking order was swapped
...
```

Failing to do some form of `SELECT ...LOCK/UPDATE` can easily lead to a "race condition", wherein two connections are acting on the same row(s) in inconsistent ways.

Another note:  If you "lock" the same rows in the same order, then one connection may stall until the other lets go.  (cf `innodb_lock_wait_timeout`, which defaults to 50 seconds [an excessive amount of time, in my opinion])

(All of my discussion should apply to all versions of InnoDB/XtraDB in either MySQL or MariaDB.)